# .NET application (WinForms) depending on ASP.NET Core server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

```
   Control Panel     ----------->        Server
  .NET Framework      depends on      ASP.NET Core
                       ⚡ FAIL ⚡
```

I have a web server built with ASP.NET Core 2.1, because it should run both on a normal desktop computer (Windows 10) and a Raspberry Pi (Windows 10 IoT Core). Works fine so far.

Just in the case the server is running on a desktop computer, I want to provide a control panel for the server based on WinForms (.NET Framework 4.7). Therefore (and for other additional functionality needed for the desktop version) I created a second project using .NET Framework 4.7, which includes the server project as a dependency.

Unfortunately, this does not work. Visual Studio tells me, that the target version "netcoreapp2.1" of the server is not compatible with the version ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" of the control panel. Also referencing the server DLL instead of the project does not work (compiles fine, but runtime error when calling the server).

Is there an elegant solution (beside creating two separate exe files and using some form of interprocess communication)?

**EDIT:** I know I can move shared code into a .NET Standard class library project. But my problem is the ASP.NET Core specific code, like say calling `Server.Start()` from the control panel, where `Server` is specific to ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use a ".NET Standard" project for the ASP.NET Core server and install the ASP.NET Core dependencies also on the WinForms project.**

Long answer:

The problem is, that Visual Studio creates the ASP.NET Core project based on ".NET Core", but not on ".NET Standard". So we can not depend on it. But we can change this. This is the whole project setup:

1) As the control panel project, create a solution with a WinForms (".NET Framework") project. Let's call the project `WinForms`.

2) Add a ASP.NET Core web application project to the solution. Let's call it `Server`. As a template, select the "API" template and choose the ".NET Core" version "ASP.Net Core 2.1".

3) In the `WinForms` project, add a dependency on the `Server` project. Add a line for launching the server by calling `Server.Program.Main(new string[0]);`

4) In the `Server` project, in the `Main` method of `Program.cs`, I launch the web host by calling `RunAsync()` instead of `Run()`, so that the call does not block and my Winforms project will be able to proceed.

When you try to compile `WinForms` project now, you see exactly the error which I described in my question: The ".NET Framework" project does not accept a ".NET Core" project as a dependency. Luckily, the `Server` project actually complies to the ".NET Standard", so we can change this now:

4) Close Visual Studio. Open `Server.csproj` in a text editor and replace the line `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` by `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`.

5) Open the solution in Visual Studio again. Now we see problems with the NuGet packages in the `Server` project. Open the NuGet package manager and uninstall "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App". Instead, install both "Microsoft.AspNetCore" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc". If you have a look at their dependencies, you will see that they both conform to the ".NET Standard".

6) Now the solution compiles fine. But when running the `WinForms` project, I get a runtime exception when the server is called. Some assembly files are missing. I guess, this is because we need the ".NET Framework" variants of those assembly files.

7) Therefore, in the `WinForms` project also open the NuGet package manager and install both dependencies "Microsoft.AspNetCore" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" there, too! You will see that the ".NET Framework" variants are downloaded.

8) Run the `WinForms` project, and now, it works :-D

Comment: works fine, however i also had to install other nuget packages too which were used in the Server Project

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at the table available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

It describes the possible combinations for each platform by targeting different version of the .NET standard specification.

Here is one possible way to make it work for you.

In your Visual Studio solution, create your ASP.NET Core Web Application, in my test I used .NET Core 2.0 as the target.

Then create a new class library that targets .NET Standard 2.0:

[image: .NET Standard Class Library]

Add a reference to this library to your ASP.NET Web application.

Then add your WinForms project, according the table above, it should target **.NET Framework 4.6.1** not .NET Framework 4.7 (I don't think there is any advantage of using the latest version for WinForms anyway).

Then add a reference to the .NET Standard class library to the WinForms project.

Use this library for anything you need to share between the WinForm application and the Website.

**Edit**

To access ASP.NET Core functionality from your shared library, you can add the NuGet `Microsoft.AspNetCore` or any other package you need that supports .NET Standard 2.0:

[image: NuGet .NET Standard]

You may also need to add some NuGet packages to your WinForms projects, same principle applies, as long as you target .NET Framework 4.6.1 and your NuGet packages support .NET Standard 2.0 it should work.

Comment: Yes, I can share the common code in a .NET standard project, but this does not solve the problem that I can not control the server from the WinForms control panel. For example I need to call `Server.Start()`, but the `Server` class is _not_ .NET Standard but specific to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Btw why don't you use the .NET core command line commads to start and stop the server from your winforms app? That will be much easier IMHO.

Comment: When possible, I'd like to have a single exe file with the ASP.NET Core server baked in. (This has more reasons, e.g. I need some other functions from the .NET Framework like accessing serial ports.)
Of course I could use the command line to control a separate server exe. This is what I meant when I said "beside ... using some form of interprocess communication".
My next try is to get rid of all parts of ASP.NET Core which are not compatible with .NET Standard, as described here: https://www.sourceallies.com/2016/12/build-a-restful-service-with-dotnet-core/
I will post the result here.

Comment: I found a solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) exists. Create a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project. Then, move all the common functionality there. Finally, have both your .NET Framework and .NET Core projects reference that class library.

Comment: Please see my comment below lsma's answer why this does not solve my problem.